# How can I add at runtime a new RuntimePermission to Java security policy?

Tags: java, security, permissions

I want to add at runtime a new RuntimePermission to the set of already existing permissions (**java.policy**) file.
Here is my code:

```
ProtectionDomain domain = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain();
        final PermissionCollection domainPerms = domain.getPermissions();
        Enumeration<Permission> oldPerms = domainPerms.elements();
        PermissionCollection newPerms = new Permissions();

        //add the old permissions to
        while (oldPerms.hasMoreElements()) {
            newPerms.add(oldPerms.nextElement());
        }
        //add my new permission
        RuntimePermission rtPermission = new RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers");
        newPerms.add(rtPermission);
```

..

But how do I use the `newPerms` object ?

Also I've tried to add the new permission to the `oldPerms` but since `oldPerms` is read only, I get a nice SecurityException.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Permissions` types have a very strange API, although it shouldn't be too surprising that you can't modify an object that has been set read-only. `ProtectionDomain`s are supposed to be immutable.

However, since about 1.4ish you can have "dynamic" `ProtectionDomain`s that defer to the current `Policy`. However, trying to change permissions on the fly is not something I would advise, as it doesn't make a great deal of sense. better to create APIs with a capability approach - the `SecurityManager` is just there paper over the cracks in bad APIs.